# Turn off App-Info Battery Optimization from Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, battery

I am running an app which needs to run a service in the background using IMU (accelerometer and gyroscope data) in the background, while the app is in background and the screen is off. After sometime, the IMU data stops as Android pushes the app into background. I need to disable this from inside Kotlin.
As of now, the only way I found is to redirect the user to
`Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`.
However, from here setting the app battery settings to Do-not-optimize is different from OEM to OEM and also varies from one version of Android to another ([Screen Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxaaf.png))

How can I edit this setting from within my code?

PS:
I have already tried power settings and other App Optimizations from Battery Settings but it does not change the settings inside the App-Info page.

EDIT 1: Since it is not possible to edit this setting, can I somehow get a System message in my app when the app actually goes to sleep

Comment: Which service you're using in your project. Try foreground service..

Comment: I am using Location Service... I have put it into a foreground service but as soon as I turn off my screen the same issue occurs. The only functional method to avoid that is to disable battery optimization inside app-info. But it varies vastly across devices. Hence I have posted this question. @GobuCSG

Comment: I believe you can't change the setting... It's user preferences

Answer (score 0):

> I am running an app which needs to run a service in the background using IMU (accelerometer and gyroscope data) in the background, while the app is in background and the screen is off.

The behavior of sensors in the background will vary by device model, particularly for older Android versions. There are tens of thousands of Android device models.

> After sometime, the IMU data stops as Android pushes the app into background. I need to disable this from inside Kotlin

There is no Android SDK method for this, sorry.

> However, from here setting the app battery settings to Do-not-optimize is different from OEM to OEM and also varies from one version of Android to another (Screen Sample)

Correct. The same thing is true for background sensor access.